# How to prevent "Add to home screen" from appearing on certain urls of same webapp?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, react-typescript

I have a webapp that shows some content on say,
`test.com` and `special.test.com`

I have setup PWA using React Typescript + PWA template.
The "Add to Home Screen" appears on both the urls.

Is their a way to prevent the install option from appearing in `special.test.com`

```
self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  const subdomainName = self.location.host.split('.')[0];
  console.log('PWA_INSTALL_CALL', subdomainName);
  if (subdomainName === 'special') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I have added this event listener to `service-worker.ts` but this function doesn't seem to be called since I'm not seeing console.log statement on Chrome dev console.

Really stuck here!
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you have complete control over when and where that prompt displays. In your case I would either not include the script on those pages or build a black list of URLs to block the prompt.
The browser does not just automatically prompt the user to install. You have to call the event..prompt() method to trigger that prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for `beforeinstallprompt` in the application context, not in a service worker context.